# How to copy data from worksheet to new worksheet a variable number of times?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column of headers in Sheet(2), Column A through Row 108. Columns B through J have data related to those headers. I need to copy Column A with Column B into Sheet(3) "X" times based on an integer in a cell in Sheet(1) into Columns B and C of Sheet(3). This needs to be repeated for each Column B-J making sure to take the header Column A, and paste it "X" times based on an integer in a cell in Sheet(1) into Column B and C of Sheet(3). I need the copy and paste to begin to repeat in Sheet(3) in the row following the last paste of data.

An additional requirement is for each time the two columns of data [meaning Column A and one of the Columns B-J of Sheet(2)] is pasted into Sheet(3), a week of the year is tagged in Column A of Sheet(3) for each row of the data pasted based on a start date in Sheet(1). The week of the year should continue to move away from the start date by one week with every paste of Sheet(2) data into Sheet(3).

Also if the VBA is run again it needs to override the data pasted not continue down the column.

Comment: I can't quite follow your requirements.  Please edit your question and try and be more clear about what you are asking for?

Comment: Have you done any work to accomplish this yourself yet? E.g. used the Macro recorder to get yourself started on at least the code to copy stuff over?

Comment: Yes, I know How to select and copy over, but it is more adding the integer component so it repeats pasting and also pastes again into the next open row. And then moves through to paste columns A&B, A&C, A&D...through A&J into columns B & C of Sheet(3)

Comment: All this data that is now in these columns was in an various tables, so copy and pasting has been figured out.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your problem. This code takes the number of times to copy/iterate from cell A1 of Sheet1, then it copies data from Sheet2 (Cell B2 to the end of the data set) and pastes it multiple times into Sheet 3:

```
'assumes parameter is in cell A1
num_iterations = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

data_last_row = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

'Copy records from data tab, assuming data starts in B2
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2:B" & data_last_row).Copy

For i = 1 To num_iterations
    output_last_row = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(output_last_row + 1, 1).PasteSpecial 
Next i
```

Comment: This is really helpful! A couple questions for you though. And maybe should edit my question a bit.

Comment: I have a column of headers in Sheet(2), Column A through Row 108. Columns B through J have data related to those headers. I need to copy Column A with Column B into Sheet(3) "X" times based on an integer in a cell in Sheet(1) into Columns B and C of Sheet(3). This needs to be repeated for each Column B-J making sure to take the header Column A, and paste it  "X" times based on an integer in a cell in Sheet(1) into Column B and C of Sheet(3). I need the copy and paste to begin to repeat in Sheet(3) in the row following the last paste of data.

Comment: A little unclear on what exactly you want this to look like. It shouldn't be too difficult if it is just copy/pasting based on certain column/row references, though! I'd recommend testing out a few things (using my code or recording your own macros)

Comment: Could you clarify how to get your code to copy Column A and B of Sheet(2) into columns B & C of Sheet(3). Then moving to Column A and C, then A & D, and so on to A & J all into the same columns B & C of Sheet(3). Reminder that each time it paste it needs to duplicate X times based on an integer in Sheet(1) cell. And pasting should continue into the next open row.

Comment: With your code, I was having trouble getting the next set of columns A &C, A&D and so on into the same Columns in sheet(3). It will post A into A, and C into C, but I need into to post always into the first two or same two columns?